# Tracking humans with ceiling-mounted downwards-pointing webcams

Tags: opencv, cuda, computer-vision, tracking, detection

I need to track people walking around inside a building. I have a downwards-pointing webcam mounted in the ceiling 6 meters (20 ft) above ground.

**Performance is important** as the plan is to have it running in real-time on several webcams. Currently I have a single camera mounted, and with background subtraction using VIBE on GPU I am getting ~320 fps on 720p which is great.

While VIBE performs well I am struggling with consistency. If people walk too close to each other they are considered to be one blob. I also need to ignore movement from non-human objects.

**I really need some input and ideas from you people** on how to determine what is a human and what is not in my VIBE output. What would be sensible approaches? I have tried to define humans as having a certain square pixel size, but I feel there must be smarter ways to discriminate humans from non-human motion.

If an alternative approach would make sense e.g. optical flow, a tracking-learning-detection algorithm (OpenTLD?), a well-performing HOG, I would be very interested in hearing about it.

Any thoughts and input is appreciated :)

Comment: I would attach tag [computer-vision] as well.

Answer (score 2):

There are many approaches to your problem, none of which work universally.  The two major families of approaches are to (a) improve the lower-level blob detection and processing or (b) handle the ambiguities in your tracker.

If you have ideas about how to improve the blob detection, try those.  I'm not familiar with VIBE or the details of your scene (indoor vs. outdoor, amount of camera shake, lens quality, etc.), so I don't have suggestions there.

Assuming that the merged blobs are from independent pedestrians, Consider using a particle filter that understands blob splits and merges.  If people move in large groups, consider enhancing the tracker to detect groups of people and giving up tracking each person individually.

If you can build a robust tracker, you may be able to filter out non-humans by both their motion pattern and pixel size.

Comment: Thank you for the input. The camera is mounted in the ceiling and is not moving. The scene is inside a building. I really need to keep tracking people even if they move into large groups and the blobs merge. Do you have a link that would explain your particle filter approach?

Comment: Try reading about multiple-hypothesis trackers in your favorite computer vision textbook.  Particle filters are one technique.  Also, here's a like to one academic paper that tries to address the problem: http://people.csail.mit.edu/cielbleu/pubs/BoseEtalCVPR07Multiclass.pdf

Comment: Very nice. I will look into that. Thanks a lot!